# LINQ query for getting items that match all items of an array of IDs

Tags: linq, postgresql

I have an externally passed array of IDs passed to my method.

Task:

- Table A contains a group ID and a sub ID, among other things
- There is one sub ID per row in table A
- There is one group ID per row in table A
- There are normally multiple rows that have a matching group ID but different Sub IDs
- I want to get the group entries which when combined have all the sub Ids in the externally passed array of IDs.

My query so far:

```
var externallyPassedArrayOfIds = [1, 2, 3]; 

var members = db.TableA
            .Where(u => externallyPassedArrayOfIds.Contains(u.SubId))
            .GroupBy(u => u.GroupId)
            .ToList();
```

An example of what could be in the DB and which ones would get selected (ordered by group id only for easy understanding):

```
ID | GroupId | SubId
---------------------
1    1         4
2    1         1
3    2         1
4    2         2
5    2         4
6    2         5
7    3         1
8    3         2
9    3         3
10   3         4
11   4         1
12   4         2
13   4         3
```

In this example, it would return rows 7,8,9,11,12,13 because only group ids 3 and 4 have all the subIds in the array. If this could be all one query that would be great, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: First you need to join and then perform a group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want items where *all* `externallyPassedArrayOfIds` are included, use `All` to check this condition on the group, not on individual items:

```
var members = db.TableA
    .GroupBy(u => u.GroupId)
    .Where(g => externallyPassedArrayOfIds.All(id => g.Any(i => i.SubId == id)))
    .ToList();
```

The `Where` clause applies to the entire group as a whole. It says that group must be such that for each element `id` of `externallyPassedArrayOfIds` there is at least one element `i` of the group `g` with `i.SubId` equal to `id`.